# Several currency symbols in same column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, symbols, currency

How can I insert currency symbol (like $, €..) under 'Price' column, when I have different currencies in the same column?

```
data = [['Shampoo', 0.60, 'USD'], 
        ['Soap', 0.19, 'EURO'], 
        ['Pen', 0.1, 'JPY'], 
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Stuff', 'Price', 'Currency'])
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `mapping` dictionary that maps each currency to its corresponding symbol then use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the values in `currency` column, then concatenate the mapped column with `price` column:

```
mapping = {'USD': '$', 'EURO': '€', 'JPY': '¥'}
df['Price'] = df['Currency'].map(mapping) + df['Price'].astype(str)
```

---

```
# print(df)
     Stuff  Price Currency
0  Shampoo   $0.6      USD
1     Soap  €0.19     EURO
2      Pen   ¥0.1      JPY
```

Comment: how did you get the JPY symbol ?

Comment: @RajMehta Simply search on the internet or look up in your computers character map. Look here [currency symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_symbol).

Comment: Shubham- Thank you! 
If I am not wrong, what I understand is that the mapping function is basically concatenating two strings, by matching value in the currency column.
Regarding JPY currency, what I wanted to understand was if there is a library you used there or via keyboard.

Comment: I suggest you take look at the documentation, i have provided the link to the documentation of `Series,map` in the answer.  Regarding the symbol, I manually typed it. Also if this answered your question please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
curr = {
    'USD': '$',
    'EURO': '€',
    'JPY': '¥',
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Stuff', 'Price', 'Currency'])
df['Price'] = df.apply(lambda x: curr[x['Currency']] + ' ' + str(x['Price']), axis=1)
print(df)

     Stuff   Price Currency
0  Shampoo   $ 0.6      USD
1     Soap  € 0.19     EURO
2      Pen   ¥ 0.1      JPY
```